# Google Search Console API: Adding domains does not work

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-search-console

I have this code for adding a new domain to the Google search console:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient._auth import credentials_from_file

service = build('searchconsole', 'v1', credentials=credentials_from_file('/md/setup/domains/service_account_key.json'))
sites = service.sites()
sites.add(siteUrl='https://www.mydomaindfvfvui4fu9neriern.com').execute()
print(sites.list().execute())
service.close()
```

It runs successfully and afterwards the list shows the domain is added:

`{'siteEntry': [{'siteUrl': 'https://www.mydomaindfvfvui4fu9neriern.com/', 'permissionLevel': 'siteUnverifiedUser'}]}`

However, in the web browser at https://search.google.com/search-console the domain does not show up. The key I use above is tied to the Google account I'm using in the browser. Also, I have other code for verifying a domain using `siteVerification` API with the same credentials which works. Only `sites.add()` seems to somehow perform its actions on some other instance. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: I believe the reason this does not work is that each user has its own state of the search console. So everything works as the service user. The problem is, I cannot log in as the service user to administer my domains in the web browser, and I cannot use my Google account for the API as far as I'm aware. So it seems it is not possible to automatically add all domains _and_ have them show up in the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the OAuth flow to log in as the Google account user.  This has been confirmed here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/1647

Full example code is here:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user